# Occasional "Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class androidx.lifecycle.y that is not a Fragment"

Tags: android, androidx

I want to emphasize first that this exception is extremely rare. I am asking out of curiosity more than anything else. It occurs no more than 0.01% of the time. Since the app has a large installation base, we see it in analytics.

```
public class AppCompatFoo extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}

public class AppFooActivity
        extends AppCompatFoo {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
    }
}
```

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) occasionally throws:

```
android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException
 Stack trace: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class androidx.lifecycle.y that is not a Fragment
        at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:538)
        at android.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:53)
        at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:77)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2867)
        at android.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:142)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1501)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:88)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:363)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:217)
```

Wonder if anyone could offer a hint about the possible causes. Again, it is extremely rare. It is really not a problem.

Comment: Have same problem, is extremely rare but exists, for now have 2 occurrences on 200k user base, it happens after app init when try to show main activity

Comment: Have the same problem. 33 crashes and all of them on Lenovo Tab M10 FHD Plus, Android 10. Looks like some device-os-specific bug.

Comment: @Dmitriy I have noticed that a lot of these crashes are specific to certain brands. Xiaomi devices are the most prone to all sorts of weird crashes. Lenovo is better than Xiaomi, but worse than other brands. This is just my impression from looking crash reports.